# Force 2 Factor Authentication for new users when they login for the first time .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, .net-6.0

I am trying to configure the 2FA when users log in for the first time in .net core. So I added an if condition for checking if 2FA is not enabled then redirecting to creating MFA, however, a major flaw here is that the users can change the URL link on the browser to skip 2FA creation, how can I avoid this? Below are my Account Controller Codes:

**Login Controller Methods**

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string? returnurl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string? returnurl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl;
            returnurl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (user.TwoFactorEnabled==false)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(EnableAuthenticator), new { returnurl, model.RememberMe });
                    }
                    return LocalRedirect(returnurl);
                }

                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(VerifyAuthenticatorCode), new { returnurl, model.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    return View("Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Enable 2FA Controller Methods**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EnableAuthenticator()
    {
        string AuthenticatorUriFormat = "MY-OTP-SECRET-HERE";

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        await _userManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
        var token = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
        string AuthenticatorUri = string.Format(AuthenticatorUriFormat, _urlEncoder.Encode("My-App-Name-Here"),
            _urlEncoder.Encode(user.Email), token);
        var model = new MFAViewModel() { Token = token, QRCodeUrl = AuthenticatorUri };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EnableAuthenticator(MFAViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var succeeded = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider, model.Code);
            if (succeeded)
            {
                await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Verify", "Your two factor auth code could not be validated.");
                return View(model);
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(AuthenticatorConfirmation));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean about that "users can change the URL link on the browser to skip 2FA creation"? From your code, it seems that after user login success, it will check the user's TwoFactorEnabled property to verify whether user need to make the 2 Factor Authentication, how to control it via changing the URL Link?

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv, thanks for the reply, My requirement is to enforce 2FA. All users must register 2FA on their first login. So according to the logic posted above, Once a user logs in if 2FA is disabled it redirects to Enable2FA Action method. But if I manually change the URL on the browser it allows me to skip creating 2FA, and access the dashboard. It seems I have to check this on each controller with above logic, I,am looking for a centralized solution for the application.

Comment: You could consider configuring the application use [Claims-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0), after user login with 2FA successfully, you could add a claim store the 2FA login result and add it to the login user. After that, in your application, create a policy which requires the claim, and add the Authorize attribute on each controller.

Comment: Besides, you could also add the user's claims after 2FA  , then create a custom middleware/Authorize attribute to validate each request and check whether the current user contains the claims or not. You can refer to the following links: [Custom Authorization attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-authorization-attributes) and [How To Override Attribute Class To Do Custom Authorization In .NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-override-customauthorization-class-in-net-core/).

Comment: Dear Zhiv,
Many Thanks for the solution! 
Yes I will be doing that. I will create a claim for 2FA and then assign the attribute.

Comment: @ZhiLv If you can post this as answer I can accept it as solution

Comment: Dear @ahp, glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issues.

Comment: Im, unable to upvote as a new user, I have accepted as solution. Many thanks for the support provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you could consider configuring the application use [Claims-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0), after user login with 2FA successfully, you could add a claim store the 2FA login result and add it to the login user. After that, in your application, create a policy which requires the claim, and add the Authorize attribute on each controller.

Besides, you could also add the user's claims after 2FA , then create a custom middleware/Authorize attribute to validate each request and check whether the current user contains the claims or not. You can refer to the following links: [Custom Authorization attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-authorization-attributes) and [How To Override Attribute Class To Do Custom Authorization In .NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-override-customauthorization-class-in-net-core/).